# How can is it possible to use new initialized node inside of itself?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

here I use n node inside of it as "struct n *next" how is this possible or what is the meaning of it ?

```
struct n {
    int data;
    struct n *next ;
};
```

Comment: Your `struct n` has the address of another `struct n`, that's it. Looks like a linked list, wehre each node know it's successor. And about the "how is this possible": your `struct n` just has a pointer member variable. Just like I'm a person and I have some sheet of paper with the address of another person.

Comment: Have you been introduced to pointers? `struct n *next;` is a pointer to a `struct n` named `next`.

Comment: Like @StefanRiedel said, you don't need to know everything about someone to write down their address. So you can write pointers to structs even before they are fully defined.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**
It's a pointer

---

There is an entity in C and C++ called pointer. It is a variable contains address in memory where actual value stored. In your case you say to compiler "I want to store address of next node in this variable". `struct n` just type name, `next` is variable name and `*` is mark to compiler that that variable is a pointer.

If you want to learn a little more about pointers I recommend you to read great book called "Using and understanding C pointers".